# How to cleanly clipboard copy code from a GitHub.com diff?

Tags: github

Consider the following split view code diff from a browser on GitHub.com:

[image: diff]

While looking at this diff, I want to clipboard copy the code from the right-hand side (e.g. in order to paste that snippet into a different project in another window).

However, if I try to use the mouse to select the code on the right-hand side in the usual fashion, the code from *both sides* ends up selected:

[image]

And if I hit Ctrl+C / Cmd+C, I end up with kind of a mess on my clipboard which includes copies of the code from *both* sides, *and* all of the `+` and `-` indicators, which leaves me with a lot of error-prone manual cleanup to do after I paste. (Particularly when copying from a diff that's more long and complex then the simple one I picked out for illustration purposes in this question!)

My question: How can I cleanly and easily copy code from one side of a split view diff in a web browser on GitHub.com to my clipboard?

Comment: I'm not sure what GitHub was thinking when they created it this way. Makes copying from diffs a nightmare... : /

Comment: Update: the refined-github extension now (Nov. 2020) allows for a clean copy. See my [updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50124517/6309).

Comment: Update March 2021: this should be finally supported! Without any extension. See [my updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50124517/6309).

Comment: @VonC While the most recent update does handle most common use-cases, if you want to copy any context reveled by clicking the arrows that show the surrounding code, it still has the same issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update March 2021: this should be, this time, supported:

> ### [Copy one side of split diff](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-19-copy-one-side-of-split-diff/)
>
> When comparing changes to a file using the split view, you can now select and copy just one side of the diff.
> Previously both sides were copied. Selecting over a comment will still copy the comment's contents.
>
> [image: split diff -- https://i1.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/7900087/110049768-5b9a1600-7d07-11eb-80eb-52ef1ada617c.gif?ssl=1]

---

May 2018:

As mentioned by [Hugo Giraudel](https://twitter.com/HugoGiraudel) in [his tweet](https://twitter.com/i/web/status/990878588307165184) in late April 2018, a bit too quickly:

> GitHub *finally* moved the `+` and `-` symbols from diffs to CSS pseudo-elements, **making it possible to copy code directly from a diff without having to clean it up**.
> That is long overdue and fantastic. ✨

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DcBOo-tXcAArfD_.jpg:large]

Actually... this is only true with the help of third-party extension!
Like [`sindresorhus/refined-github`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github).

Without, you would still copy the '`+`' and '`-`'.
GitLab has that feature though.
This is still pending for BitBucket ([issue 16204](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/16204/move-the-and-symbols-from-diffs-to-css))

[timotheecour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426932/timotheecour) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446463/how-to-cleanly-clipboard-copy-code-from-a-github-com-diff/50124517#comment106307421_50124517) that it does not help with side-by-side diffs:

> the code from both sides ends up selected

This is in the context of using [`refined-github`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github), a Browser extension that simplifies the GitHub interface: [issue 2765](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/issues/2765).
Update Nov. 2020: that issue just got resolved with [PR 3698](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/pull/3698)

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/46634000/98137788-abd0ab00-1ec2-11eb-9e04-6f20786d5dd8.gif]

Comment: this doesn't help at all with the following though:
`the code from both sides ends up selected` ; I've also asked here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/issues/2765

Comment: @timotheecour Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @Disappointed That seems expected: https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/commit/ea6c3bf37f698a4b6a2eadd689ef2a09ec93c477, which is referenced by that PR, is not yet part of a release for that plugin. (https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/releases). It should be released soon.

Comment: @Disappointed https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/releases/tag/20.11.12 is out! That release should include the single-diff-column-selection feature.